# djangocms-text-ckeditor and django-filer with custom app

Tags: python, django

I'm using DjangoCMS 3.0 with Django 1.6 and django-filer.
I need a wysiwyg editor for some fields of my custom app. Since with the CMS I have installed djangocms-text-ckeditor, I tried to use it also for my model, like this:

```
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField

class Post(models.Model):
    description = HTMLField(_('description'), blank=True, null=True)
```

This solution seems to work, but I can't add images inside it.

1) How can I add images inside CKeditor widget using cmsplugin_filer_image plugin?

2) Is it a good practice to use djangocms-text-ckeditor outside the CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. AFAIK, you can't.
   Or by switching CKEditor to "HTML mode" and adding your `<img>` tag with the source hosted externally.
   Likewise for all nested plugins (link, image, file, columns, etc.) which need a placeholder to handle the nested structure.
2. Yes, but not for complex contents, like medias. Then you can use a `PlaceholderField` but this is only manageable by staff users through the django-cms frontend editing feature.